# Find fields with null values and count them in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I wanna find fields in my database that has null values in them. I read in some other thread here on stackoverflow that you could try to use $ne (not equal) but didn't get that to work for me, so I'm thinking it might be something else I have done wrong.

Here is an example from my database:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5695553244aec8a25d162698"), "DBLPKey" : "journals/software/Goth08a", "LastModified" : "2011-11-07", "Authors" : [  {  "Name" : "Greg Goth",  "Affiliation" : null } ], "Title" : "Ultralarge Systems: Redefining Software Engineering?", "Pages" : "91-94", "Year" : "2008", "Volume" : "25", "Journal" : "IEEE Software", "Number" : "3", "ElectronicEdition" : "http://doi.ieeecomputersociety.org/10.1109/MS.2008.82", "LocalURL" : "db/journals/software/software25.html#Goth08a", "Abstracts" : "Ultra-Large-Scale Systems: The Software Challenge of the Future, a report produced by Carnegie Mellon University's Software Engineering Institute, just might be a watershed blueprint for the next generation of top-level software design. Although it's written with a distinct slant toward the US military's future requirements, its description of how the fundamental principles of software design will change in a global economy—defined by ubiquitous computing—are finding wide appeal." }
```

The field I wanna find here is the field called Affiliation inside Author. 
I have tried this query:

```
db.Articles.find({Affiliation:{ $ne: null}})
```

but that doesn't work for me. Is it because I somehow have to tell MongodDB that it's inside the field Author? Or is it some other things that I have misunderstood or have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)

Try this,

```
db.Articles.find({ "Authors": { $elemMatch: {"Affiliation" : null } } } )
```

Comment: Will try that immediately! :)

Edit: Thanks man, worked perfectly! :)